# FSM aiogram есть ли смысл вынести в другой файл

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Делаю тг бота и появился  вопрс есть ли смысл переносить FSM в другой файл, и будет ли оно работать, сам пытаюсь сделать это уже неделю не получается, может действительно так нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден, да вынести можно, есть ли смысл? Точно НЕ знаю наверняка в больших проектах так и делают.